# I want to add three list on dialog in android

Tags: android

I am trying to add three listview on one dialog which occur on button click

```
      //Prepare ListView in dialog
      dialog_ListView = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialoglist);
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
      // custom adapter on listView in android
      CustomListviewAdapter adapter2 = new CustomListviewAdapter(MainActivity.this, listContent);
      dialog_ListView.setAdapter(adapter);

      dialog_ListView1=(ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialoglist1);
      ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent2);
      CustomListviewAdapter adapter3=new CustomListviewAdapter(MainActivity.this,listContent2);
      dialog_ListView1.setAdapter(arrayadapter);

      dialog_ListView2=(ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialoglist2);
      ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent3);
      CustomListviewAdapter adapter4=new CustomListviewAdapter(MainActivity.this,listContent3);
      dialog_ListView2.setAdapter(arrayadapter1);
```

Comment: Also, why do you want 3 separate `ListView`s in a dialog? That doesn't seem like a very good design to me

Comment: Maybe an ExpandableListView with all group extended by default will be better than 3 ListViews in the same layout. There might be a strange scroll behaviour...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to arrange three ListViews in a row or in a column?
If you want to arrange them in a column,I suggest that you can use ExanpandableListView.
Else you can accept the previous advice ,but you have better do some changes like this:

```
<ListView
    *android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"*
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<ListView
    *android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"*
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<ListView
    *android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"*
    android:id="@+id/third"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Beacase the  value of match_parent is better than others in ListView

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a custom xml layout, for example dialog_lists.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Put all 3 list views inside of it as shown above, then initialize the dialog with:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    View parent = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_lists,null);
    ListView first = (ListView)parent.findViewById(R.id.first);
    ListView second = (ListView)parent.findViewById(R.id.second);
    ListView third = (ListView)parent.findViewById(R.id.third);

    first.setAdapter(...);
    second.setAdapter(...);
    third.setAdapter(...);

    builder.setView(parent);
    builder.setNeutralButton("Close", null);
    builder.create().show();
```

Note: I have to add that this would be a horrible design choice, especially when I imagine a dialog like this on a small screen.